# Rename "all actions" tab in your profile to just "actions"

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Very recently the "activities" tab in the user profile was renamed to "all actions":

[image]

I think that should be renamed to "actions".  If you are going to call it "all actions", then why not call the other tabs "all answers", "all questions", etc.?

Also, if you're on "all actions", but you don't have the subtab on "all", then it really isn't showing "all actions" anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Agree.

For instance, in a user profile page, ex:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/32453/rogerdpack?tab=activity

there is a tab "all actions" which includes information from various of the other tabs, like badges, answers, and questions.

Somewhat unrelated, but I would have expected it to also show upvoting, as to me, voting is an action, and it advertised showing "all" of them.  The nomenclature is confusing, currently voting is shown in a separate tab.

Suggest the "voting" tab be moved to a sub tab of "all actions" or that the "all" part of the name be removed, as suggested by the OP, since then you might know to look for voting only elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure this really counts as an answer, it's not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Yes, it was more like tangentially related, and the suggestion from the OP would have "fixed" it as it were.  Should I repost it as a new question do you think?

Comment: About the votes not in the all tab, I think so yeah.  That's just my opinion though.